# Negative expression ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a parser but I don't know why I can't parse this:

```
Proceso A
    varX <- - 4;
FinProceso
```

I'm getting

```
line 2:12 extraneous input '-' expecting {NEGOP, '(', '-', INT, DOUBLE, STRING, BOOL, ID}
```

This is my grammar in ANTLR

[Grammar](http://pastebin.com/0UFDAWFn)

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Your grammar consists of two lexems matching a character `-` : **SUMOP** and **NEG**. In your case the **SUMOP** lexem will be always produced by the lexer, because it is defined before **NEG** lexem. Therefore a rule **operatorUnary** is never used.

```
SUMOP : ('+' | '-');
NEG : '-';

expr
    : expr SUMOP expr
    | operatorUnary expr
    ;

operatorUnary: '-';
```

## Solution

You should orginize your lexems. For example you can delete the **NEG** lexem and make use of only the **SUMOP** lexem.

```
SUMOP : ('+' | '-');

expr
    : SUMOP expr           // higher precedence
    | expr SUMOP expr      // lower precedence
    ;
```

Also it is often a good idea to make an unary negation operator with higher precedence than the binary addition and/or substraction operator. You can achive this by changing the order of rule **expr** alternatives.